# Why my code throws thread aborted error?

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, webforms, transmitfile

I am using this code to download file but it throws error. Please help me in handling it.

Thread was being aborted.

```
protected void Download_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string filePath = Convert.ToString(Attachment);
        string fullFilePath = ("../../SiteImages/" + "donald.jpg");
        Response.Clear();
        Response.ClearHeaders();
        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + Path.GetFileName(fullFilePath) + "\"");
        Response.ContentType = ContentType;
        Response.TransmitFile(fullFilePath);
        //MngLogs.InsertAuditsInfo("Tender downloaded via" + " " + MngLogs.PageName, MngLogs.UserMacAddress, MngLogs.UserIPAddress, UserID, "Download");
        //Response.End();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Utility.Msg_Error(Master, ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where did you get the error? `Reponse.End()` always throws a `ThreadAbortException`. Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20988445/how-to-avoid-response-end-thread-was-being-aborted-exception-during-the-exce) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5834049/what-causes-thread-was-being-aborted-exception-to-happen-at-random-and-show-th) post.

Comment: yes same place and i removed it but still it doesn't download a file

Comment: and doesn't throw error but still doesn't download a file

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ThreadAbortException (WebClient using DownloadFile to grab file from server)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2542664/threadabortexception-webclient-using-downloadfile-to-grab-file-from-server)

Answer (score 0):

Could this download approach work?

```
try
{
    using (var client = new WebClient())
    {
        client.DownloadFile(urlToFileOnInternet, pathToFileOnComputer);
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Utility.Msg_Error(Master, ex.Message);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: what is urlToFileOnInternet ?

Comment: Aren't you trying to download a file? Quote: "I am using this code to download file"

Comment: downloading a file from webserver to my own folder

Comment: Yes, but you'll need the download link to make that happen... Are you running this code on a computer or your webserver?

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
Response.End();
```

with this:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
HttpContext.Current.Response.SuppressContent = true;
HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
```

`Response.End();` always throw an exception cause it will abort current thread. You can read more about this behavior here: [Is Response.End() considered harmful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087777/is-response-end-considered-harmful/3917180#3917180), [How to Avoid Response.End() "Thread was being aborted" Exception during the Excel file download](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20988445/how-to-avoid-response-end-thread-was-being-aborted-exception-during-the-exce).